# What is the proper way to create this CSS selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this CSS:

```
#allStuff > div > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > h3:nth-child(3) {
border-top:1px solid #ffffff6b;
padding-top:8px;
}

#allStuff > div > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > div > h3:nth-child(3) {
border-top:1px solid #ffffff6b;
padding-top:8px;
}

#allStuff > div > div > div > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > div > h3:nth-child(3) {
border-top:1px solid #ffffff6b;
padding-top:8px;
}

#allStuff > div > div > div > div:nth-child(5) > div > div > div > h3:nth-child(3) {
border-top:1px solid #ffffff6b;
padding-top:8px;
}
```

The only difference is the first `nth-child(x)`; what's to correct way to create this selector so that I can only create a single selector to cover all of them?

i.e. something similar to this (which I know is wrong, but demonstrates what I mean):

```
#allStuff > div > div > div > div:nth-child(*) > div > div > div > h3:nth-child(3) {
border-top:1px solid #ffffff6b;
padding-top:8px;
}
```

Comment: @Joseph Unfortunately those selectors were copied from the Chrome inspector. I don't have access to the page's source itself to make permanent changes. I'm adding my tweaks via something like stylus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Use `:nth-child(n)`**  if you want to cover all the numbers (1, 2, 3, 4, 5,  ... n)

  *Quick example:*

  ```css
     
     p:nth-child(n) {
       color: red;
     }
  ```

  ```html
     
     <p>Cameras are watching us</p>
     <p>Cameras are watching us</p>
     <p>Cameras are watching us</p>
     <p>Cameras are watching us</p>
     <p>Cameras are watching us</p>
     <p>Cameras are watching us</p>
  ```
- **Use `:nth-child(-n+5):not(:first-child)`**  If you want to cover only from 2 to 5 (just like in your example)

  *Quick example:*

  ```css
     
     p:nth-child(-n+5):not(:first-child) {
       color: red;
     }
  ```

  ```html
     
     <p>Cameras are watching us</p>
     <p>Cameras are watching us</p>
     <p>Cameras are watching us</p>
     <p>Cameras are watching us</p>
     <p>Cameras are watching us</p>
     <p>Cameras are watching us</p>
  ```